# How can scientific notation be enforced?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, scientific-notation

When the axis values are have about 5 zeroes in front, Python automatically applies scientific notation on the values and puts at the end of the y-axis the power used (e.g. 1e-6). The issue is that I have other charts that have 1 and 3 zeroes in front of the axis values and I would want Python to apply scientific notation as in the image below. How can this be achieved? I would really appreciate your help. The code for my chart is:

```
plt.figure()
BarNames = ['SVR', 'LSTM', 'GRU', 'CNN']
colours = ['orange', 'green', 'darkred', 'purple']
values = [9.931470649536813e-04, 9.433767714089219e-04, 8.682655450180871e-04, 5.461618193308908e-04]
plt.bar(BarNames, values, color=colours)
plt.xlabel('CincoCrypto Models')
plt.ylabel('Mean Absolute Percentage Error (%)')
plt.savefig(f"{cryptos[2]}_MAPE", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Python plot with scientific notation]

Comment: [Asked and answered already](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+use+scientific+notation+on+axis+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thank you. I already tried it before but I don't get to make it work. It gives me the error "plt.ticklabel_format" only works with the ScalarFormatter.

This is the code of the chart I want to put in scientific notation with the "plt.ticklabel_format" line giving me the error:

Comment: `code`
plt.figure()
BarNames = ['SVR', 'LSTM', 'GRU', 'CNN']
colours = ['orange', 'green', 'darkred', 'purple']
values = [9.931470649536813e-04, 9.433767714089219e-04, 8.682655450180871e-04, 5.461618193308908e-04]

plt.bar(BarNames, values, color=colours)

plt.xlabel('CincoCrypto Models')

plt.ylabel('Mean Absolute Percentage Error (%)')

plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0)) #Line code giving me the error

plt.savefig(f"{cryptos[2]}_MAPE", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
`code`

Comment: I've already tried that. And also on ChatGPT but it has led me nowhere so far

Comment: `plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0))`. The x-axis is not numeric.

Comment: Managed to fix it: The line of code I have to use is

    plt.gca().ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0, 0))